# Prevent CSS variable inheritance || unused css propety?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any way to prevent CSS variable inheritance, the issue is that I need a lot of variables and I don't want my website slowing extremely down because each element inherits hundreds of CSS variables ?

Or

Is there a CSS property in which I can enter whatever I want and which is not used by anybody?

Comment: how you will use the variables and where you are declaring them? give us more context

Comment: One option is to look at SCSS bundles - that way you can import only the bits you need on each page.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Basically my goal is to track all styles being applied to an element, each CSS class is generated by my code and I was thinking about using empty variables to get all styles affecting an element, Im scared about performance with that approach, so I was thinking that I might use an rarely used CSS property as a container to store the id of each class, and when you select it it always removes the variable and gets the computed style again, that way I can get all selectorObjects which get applied on an element

Comment: @TemaniAfif ... why?

Comment: I need it for my project, im building a website builder, which allows you to write any kind of CSS selector, but my issue is that I don't know which ones effect which element, When it launches I could do querySelector but what after the launch when you create new Elements, I cannot loop each time though all selectors, that would be too expensive, or?

Comment: Ohhh, so it's to track the user changing stuff. If it's an option for you, it might be worth looking at jQuery. That way you can effectively store a copy of the defined style of an element within the data field - something like `$(myCSSselector).data($(myCSSselector).css())` (the syntax might not be 100% correct as it's been a while since I've had to do something similar).

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan That's not it, I might get the changing styles, but I won't be able to access the style objects from which they get inherited. https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-cssstylesheet-insertrule

Comment: For the inheritance you'd have to write a recursive function of some sort that goes up the parentElements

Comment: That wouldnt have worked, but i solved it, you can create custom CSS properties with css.registerProperty etc, anyways I did it